# Swift - Type 'MenuViewController' does not conform to protocol 'GKGameCenterControllerDelegate'

Tags: ios, xcode, delegates, swift, game-center

I am trying to use GameCenter to show the leaderboards for the high scores in my game. I have been trying to use some code to implement GameCenter but it all fails.

I'm told to set gameCenterDelegate before the GameCenter view controller is shown.

I've been told to do it like this:

```
var gcViewController: GKGameCenterViewController = GKGameCenterViewController()
gcViewController.gameCenterDelegate = self
```

but this gives me the following error:

```
Type 'MenuViewController' does not conform to protocol 'GKGameCenterControllerDelegate'
```

I tried changing this:

```
class MenuViewController: UIViewController {
```

to:

```
class MenuViewController: GKGameCenterViewControllerDelegate {
```

but this gives me loads of errors, the first of which being on this line, reading:

```
Use of undeclared type 'GKGameCenterViewControllerDelegate'
```

I have been trying to get this to work for about a fortnight, and there seems to be no solution anywhere. Can someone please help me???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `MenuViewController` needs to be both a subclass of `UIViewController` *and* to declare that it implements the delegate. If you've imported GameKit correctly, then:

```
class MenuViewController: UIViewController, GKGameCenterControllerDelegate {
   ...
}
```

should work. I agree that the syntax is a bit confusing, with no demarkation between the superclass and the implemented protocols.

Edit: Whoops, simple error. The delegate is actually `GKGameCenterControllerDelegate` not `GKGameCenterViewControllerDelegate`. Declare that you implement it as above, then actually implement the methods.

Comment: This comes up with the same 'Use of undeclared type.." error as above. I assume I'm importing GameKit correctly. I have `import GameKit` just above this line - is that correct?

Comment: Edit: Whoops, just a simple error. The type of the delegate is actually `GKGameCenterControllerDelegate`; see my edited answer.

Comment: Ohh, okay that got rid of the error on the line, `gcViewController.gameCenterDelegate = self`, but now that error (`Type 'MenuViewController' does not conform to protocol 'GKGameCenterControllerDelegate'`) is on the class declaration line?

Comment: That's because you've not implemented all the required methods of the delegate. Create a method `gameCenterViewControllerDidFinish` matching the delegate signature to silence it.